# Assign User to net use to change another users password

Tags: cmd.exe, net-use

Is it possible to assign a user to make net use run as a certain person(admin) to change another users password? Like so?:

`"/c net user /user:domain\Administrator <admin-pwd> username password /domain"`

Maybe some how using a runas or something to tell the command to run as a certain individual?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly.  There are easier ways to chnage a user's password as an Administrator

Comment: @Ramhound this is what I am trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234407/cfexecute-assigning-it-to-run-with-administrator-rights/42276531#42276531 Basically everyone is telling me cf runs the command as local system which on ours does not have permission to run net use and the network administrator will not let me change it. So i was trying to see if I can bypass it through the command line its running.

Answer (score 0):

with net user you can specify the user and password to use:

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc771865(v=ws.11).aspx

So, yes, if someone knows the admin password, "it is to change another user's password"

Comment: no i know you can use `net user <username> <password> /domain` to change the password but can I assign the person this cmd runs as. Because I am calling this command through coldfusion that does not have permissions to run net user on the service so i was trying to bypass it by giving this command admin rights. Make sense?

Comment: I think you should change your question to "how to assign permission to coldfusion to run specific command in windows", and you could read this "https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/running-coldfusion-specific-user.html"